# Recursively storing integers in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, integer

I have problem with recursive functions.

I have to build a recursive function which creates an array of integer values corresponding to the digits of a given number.

For example, if I input a number like 3562, it should look like :

```
myArray[0] = 3
myArray[1] = 5
myArray[2] = 6
myArray[3] = 2
```

Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int myFunction(int num, int lenOfNum);

int main(){
    int number;
    int lengthCount = 0;
    cout <<"Input numbers" << endl;
    cin >> number;
    int temp = number;
    for(; number != 0; number /= 10, lengthCount++);        
    number = temp;  
    cout << myFunction(number, lengthCount) << endl;            
}  

int myFunction(int num, int lenOfNum){
    int arr[lenOfNum];
    if(num > 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < lenOfNum; i++){
            arr[i] = num/=10;
            cout << "arr[" << i + 1 << " ]= " << arr[i] << endl;
        }
        return myFunction(num, lenOfNum);
    }
    else if(num == 0){
        return 0;   
    } else; 
}
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: `int arr[lenOfNum];` is a non-standard vendor compiler extension. Use `new[]` or `std::vector` instead. But you don't want to create a new array every time the function is called anyway. Create a single array in `main` instead and then pass it into the function to be populated. And you need to populate the array from back to front, not front to back, or else the digits will be stored in backwards order (`2, 6, 5, 3` instead of `3, 5, 6, 2`)

Comment: use std::vector - life always goes better with std:vector

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are calling `int arr[lenOfNum]` in each method call, which in short creates an array with a new reference to a memory location that can store lenOfNum integers.

To solve this, we declare the array in the main method and pass it as a parameter to the function.

```
int main() { 
    // somewhere in main after reading lenOfNum
    int arr[lenOfNum];
    // somewhere in main after declaring an array
    myFunction(arr, number, lengthCount - 1);
}
```

and myFunction as

```
void myFunction(int *arr, int num, int idx) {
    if (idx < 0) return;  // you've completed processing the num
    else if (num == 0) {
        arr[0] = 0;
        return;
    }

    arr[idx--] = num % 10;
    myFunction(arr, num / 10, idx);
}
```

Comment: Rather than have the recursion end on `num <= 0`, I would probably end it on `idx < 0` instead. What if the user actually enters `"0"` as input? If `cin >> number` is successful, `lengthCount` would have to be initialized to 1 instead of 0 to account for `arr[0] = 0`

Comment: my bad, didn't actually run the code, just thought it through, thanks for the heads, handled that case :)

Comment: You are not handling it very well, though. I still think `idx < 0` would make a better end condition: `void myFunction(int *arr, int num, int idx) { if (idx < 0) return; arr[idx--] = num % 10; myFunction(arr, num / 10, idx); }`

Answer (score 0):

Using vector and rest part of your example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void myFunction(vector<int> &arr, int num, int lenOfNum){
    if (num < 0) {
        return;
    }
    else if (num == 0) {
        return;
    }
    int next_idx = lenOfNum - 1;
    int digit = num % 10;
    arr[next_idx] = digit;
    myFunction(arr, num / 10, next_idx);
}


int main(){
    int number;
    int lengthCount = 0;
    cout <<"Input numbers" << endl;
    cin >> number;
    int temp = number;
    for(; number != 0; number /= 10, lengthCount++);        
    number = temp;  

    auto arr = vector<int>(lengthCount, 0);
    myFunction(arr, number, lengthCount);
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++){
         cout << "arr[" << i << " ]= " << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for positive numbers

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

std::vector<int> myFunction(int num)
{
  std::vector<int> ret;
  int irec = num / 10;
  if (irec > 0)
     ret = myFunction(irec);
  ret.push_back('0' + (num % 10));
  return ret;      
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> res = myFunction(539);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++)
        printf("%c,", res[i]);
}
```